# Content Security Policy CSP unsafe-eval on vendor files

Tags: javascript, http-headers, eval, content-security-policy

I'm fairly new to understanding CSP and maybe i'm just not going about something the right way here.

I have my white-list added for all the different policy types and `script-src 'self' <urls> unsafe-inline`

However I am getting several reports of `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source`

These are all in my vendor js file which is an minified and obfuscated collection of all our vendors. Done through an `npm build` with Webpack and Laravel mix.

How am I suppose to disable eval in my CSP when so many vendor scripts seem to require it?

Thanks!

Comment: `unsafe-inline` needs to be `'unsafe-inline'`, With single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the `'unsafe-eval'` source if you want to allow the use of `eval` as the error suggests. Using `'unsafe-inline'` allows the execution of inline scripts and inline event handlers.

`script-src 'self' <urls> 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`

Comment: But I'm trying not to use unsafe-eval. I do not want eval to be allowed. My question asks how do I disable unsafe-eval and yet still use vendor files? npm is going to build my vendor files and in a few cases my vendors are wrapped in `new Function()`. It might be an npm or webpack obfuscation setting. How do people disable unsafe-eval when npm vendor files are so prominent these days? It seems like it's not possible.

Comment: Though you wanted to allow eval since you already allow inline script. There are some problems with webpack and babel-loader using eval in some cases, search for webpack eval csp